# Date parsing code for "Jul 07, 2019" in pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas, date-parsing

I've been trying to parse the date of the form - `Jul 07, 2018` to `dd-mm-yyyy` format for my financial time series project. But being new to Pandas, I am not able to do it the usual way i.e., using

I've tried:

```
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%m/%d/%Y')
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\doc.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date',date_parser=dateparse)
```

Error is shown as:

```
ValueError: time data `Jul 07, 2019' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'
```

Comment: [Here's](http://strftime.org/) a good source to find the right codes for your parsers in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short**: the format is **`%b %d, %Y`**

You need to change the format you specified in the `dateparse`:

```
dateparse = lambda dates: pd.datetime.strptime(dates, '%b %d, %Y')
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\doc.csv', parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date',date_parser=dateparse)
```

For example:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('Jul 07, 2018', '%b %d, %Y')
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 7, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.strptime('Apr 07, 2018', '%b %d, %Y')
datetime.datetime(2018, 4, 7, 0, 0)
```

Comment: This has two issues. First, a named lambda and second, pandas comes with [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) which would not require the same implicit python loops and also accepts a format string

Comment: Also, [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) itself allows for specification of dtypes for different columns and a date format string (though I tend to do it in two parts such as my initial comment). I guess the `date_parser` argument is for formats not covered by the regular datetime syntax